# Prove $tr(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} ) = tr(\mathbf{A}) + tr(\mathbf{B})$

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, trace

Supposedly, this is an easy proof. But I'm really inexperienced and have little mathematical sophistication (trying to improve).

Prove $tr(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} ) = tr(\mathbf{A}) + tr(\mathbf{B})$

Since the size of either A or B is not defined, I guess the summation definition of trace of a matrix must be used in the proof.

So,

$tr\mathbf(A) = \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{A}_{k,k}$ where $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$

Any intuitive hints would be nice

Comment: What is the coefficients of the matrix $(A+B)_{ij}$ in terms of $A_{ij}$ and $B_{ij}$?

Comment: It is $\mathbf{A}_{ij} + \mathbf{B}_{ij}$. Right, now I see it.

Comment: @Laplace then submit an answer to your own question, to help future students! If you would be so kind, that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realized how basic this proof is thanks to [Winther](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/147873/winther)'s comment.

So the definition is that summing 2 matrices means adding each $ij$th element to get the corresponding element in a new matrix. Or,

if $\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}$, where $\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{m,n}$, then $\mathbf{C}_{ij} = \mathbf{A}_{ij} + \mathbf{B}_{ij}$

So,

Statement:

$tr(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} ) = tr(\mathbf{A}) + tr(\mathbf{B})$

Proof:

if $tr(\mathbf{A}) = \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{A}_{k,k}$, then

$tr(\mathbf{A+B}) = \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{(A+B)}_{k,k}$

By definition
$\mathbf{(A+B)}_{ij} = \mathbf{A}_{ij} + \mathbf{B}_{ij}$
thus,
$\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{(A+B)}_{k,k} = \sum_{k=1}^n (\mathbf{A}_{k,k}+\mathbf{B}_{k,k})$

Distribute the summation notation on the right hand side to get
$\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{(A+B)}_{k,k}=\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{A}_{k,k} + \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{B}_{k,k}$

Finally, replace the summation notation with trace to get

$tr(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} ) = tr(\mathbf{A}) + tr(\mathbf{B})$

Comment: Replace "the basic intuition" by "the definition".